# Java: Short-circuting && after OR

Tags: java, if-statement, short-circuiting

I understand `&&` and `||` are short circuited in Java (whereas `&` and `|` are not)

However, I do not understand why the following code (which starts off with short circuited OR but ends with && condition) is also short circuited:

```
String x, y;
if ( x.contains("this") || x.contains("that") && y.contains("something else")!= true)
```

I would think that even if condition `x.contains("this")` evaluates to true the program will still need to evaluate the last condition `y.contains("something else") != true` because there's the && operator before the last condition. But apparently this isn't the case.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: adding some braces makes it easier to understand: `if ( x.contains("this") || (x.contains("that") && y.contains("something else")!= true))`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer he's asking why it evaluates this way when "()" are not used to define which equations to evaluate first

Comment: @XtremeBaumer How are you sure this is an associative case, not a precedence case?

Comment: Side note: don't explicitly compare to `true` and `false` in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Two factors are in play here to determine the order of evaluation:

- Operation precedence, and
- Short-circuiting rules

Since `&&` has *higher* precedence than `||`, operator `&&` "stays closer to its operands", so your expression is parsed as follows:

[image: Parse tree]

Because both `&&` and `||` operators are left-to-right associative<sup>*</sup>, Java evaluates this expression left-to-right, stopping as soon as it determines the outcome. In case the string contains `"this"` substring, evaluation stops without evaluating the `&&`.

**Note:** If you are not sure of the order of operations, you can always force the order that you want by parenthesizing parts of your predicate. If the expression is not entirely obvious to you, good chances are that it is going to be non-obvious to other readers, so adding some extra parentheses is a good idea.

<sup>*</sup> Some operators are right-to-left associative. For example, assignment operator `a[i] = b + c` evaluates `b + c` before evaluating `a[i]`. Thanks [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) for a great comment.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of precedence to show that the && operation will be evaluated first? or does this the compiler simply group them accordingly before evaluating left to right?

Comment: @Sentinel Precedence helps compiler decide the second operand of `||` in the absence of parentheses. Given `A || B && C` the compiler decides that `A` is `||`'s first operand, and `B && C` is its second operand. If `||` had higher priority, then `||`'s operands would be `A` and `B`, and `&&`'s operands would be `(A || B)` and `C`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the comment! I edited to mention associativity explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of operator precedence.

The equivalent form of your (a || b && c) is (a || (b && c))

Cf. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 2):

> ...even if condition `x.contains("this")` evaluates to true the program will still need to evaluate the last condition `y.contains("something else") != true`...

Nope. :-) The operands to the `||` in that expression are

- `x.contains("this")`

and

- `x.contains("that") && y.contains("something else")!= true`

...because `&&` has higher precedence than `||` ([details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)). So if you have `a || b && c`, it's `a || (b && c)` (just like `a + b * c` is `a + (b * c)` rather than `(a + b) * c`). The precedence defines how the operands are grouped.

If you want the expression grouped differently, you can use `()` to group it.

```
if ( (x.contains("this") || x.contains("that")) && y.contains("something else")!= true)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way the syntax works in java as the && operations are grouped before the || opertaion, therefore when it reads the equation (A || B && C) it only see's comparing A || D (where D is really B && C). So when A is evaluated as True, it doesn't even need to evaluate B && C.
Refer to this link for further syntax related questions on the order of operations
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see dasblinkenlight's post and I see what you are referring to, I'll change the answer to include that thanks! it's been a good learning experience

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with [operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/). Most standard operators are binary, that is they take two *inputs* and produce an *output*. Whenever you have an expression with more than two operators, the compiler uses precedence and associativity rules to figure out how to transform that expression into one where it's clear what inputs each operations has.

In your case, you have an expression like `A || B && C`. `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so the compiler will interpret it as `A || (B && C)`, not like `(A || B) && C`, which you might get at by just looking at the expression.

This means that it's enough for `A` to be true for the whole expression to be true.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is an operator with a higher precedence than `||`.
Operators with higher precedence are evaluated before operators with lower precedence.

So here :

```
if ( x.contains("this") || x.contains("that") && y.contains("something else")!= true)
```

These two expressions are evaluated together :

```
x.contains("that") && y.contains("something else")!= true
```

So you get a conditional statement with a form such as :
 `if (something || somethingElse)`

`something` is `true`, so `somethingElse` is never evaluated.
And the whole conditional statement is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Java have some [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). You need to understand it to work with it.

---

**First of all**
In your if statement, you have two logical operators: `||` and `&&`.
You know about short circuited. But you need to know that the `&&`operator will run first than `||`.

---

**AND operator (&&)**
The `&&` operator will, first, verify the left condition. There's no need to check two of them, to `&&` return true, if the first one is true, then he can check the second.

---

**OR operator (||)**
The `||` operator will execute right after `&&`. It will verify if the two conditions return false, for this reason he needs to verify both.

---

**Parentheses**
You should know, but to make it work the way you want, you need to use parentheses `()`. To do it in the way you need, use `()` to present a new rule to your if statement:

```
if ( (x.contains("this") || x.contains("that")) && y.contains("something else")!= true)
```